# how to custom pagination in php with limited page numbers

Tags: php, pagination

I use below code for pagination.How to  add first,previous,next,last links in pagination.
 Only 9 paging numbers should allow in pagination.

EX : First , Previous . ( 9 paging numbers) ,Next ,Last

I have attached image for reference. [image]

```
<?php 
$page = $_GET['url_page'];
$limit =5;
if($page==""){
$page =1;
$start_limit =0;
$end_limit = $page * $limit;
}
else {              
$end_limit = $page * $limit; 
$start_limit =$end_limit - $limit;
}

$array_count_res = count($result_array);
$choice = ceil($array_count_res /$limit);

$previous_page = $page-1;
$next_page = $page+1;

<?php if($page !=1) {  ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $previous_page; ?>">
Previous</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php for($pa = 0 ;$pa < $choice;$pa++){ ?>             
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $pa+1; ?>">
<?php echo $pa+1;echo " "; ?></a>           
<?php } ?>
<?php if($page !=$choice) {  ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $next_page; ?>">
Next</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php  
for($m=$start_limit;$m <  $end_limit;$m++) {                                
if($result_array[$m]['name'] !="") { 
?>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have tried anything.

Comment: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2014/02/06/php-pagination-class-version-3/

Answer (score 0):

finaly i got answer

```
    <?php                
        $page = $_GET['url_page'];
        $limit =25;
        if($page==""){
        $page =1;
        $start_limit =0;
        $end_limit = $page * $limit;
        }
        else {              
        $end_limit = $page * $limit; 
        $start_limit =$end_limit - $limit;
        }
        $array_count_res = count($contacts);
        $choice = ceil($array_count_res /$limit);               
        $previous_page = $page-1;
        $next_page = $page+1;
        $first_paging = $page - 2; 
        $second_paging = $page - 1; 
        $third_paging = $page + 1;
        $four_paging = $page + 2;
        $last_page =$choice -$page;

        for($m=$start_limit;$m <  $end_limit;$m++) {                     
        ?>
            <tr><td> data</td></tr>
        <?php } ?>

  <!---pagination starts----->
        <tr><td id="importcaontact_page" >
        <?php if($page > 3) {  ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/1">
        &laquo;First</a>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if($page !=1) {  ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $previous_page; ?>">
        &laquo;Previous</a>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if($first_paging > 0 ) { ?>           
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $first_paging; ?>">
        <?php echo $first_paging; ?></a>    
        <?php } ?>  

        <?php if($second_paging > 0 ) { ?>          
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?><?php echo $second_paging; ?>">
        <?php echo $second_paging; ?></a>   
        <?php } ?>  

        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $page; ?>" id="importcon_curpage"><?php echo $page; ?></a>   

        <?php if($third_paging <= $choice ) { ?>            
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $third_paging; ?>">
        <?php echo $third_paging; ?></a>    
        <?php } ?>  

        <?php if($four_paging <= $choice ) { ?>         
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $four_paging; ?>">
        <?php echo $four_paging; ?></a> 
        <?php } ?>  


        <?php if($page !=$choice) {  ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $next_page; ?>">
        Next &raquo;</a>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if($last_page > 1) {  ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>/<?php echo $choice; ?>">
        Last &raquo;</a>
        <?php } ?>
        </td></tr>
```